# Help me understand this netstat report

Tags: troubleshooting

I am IT admin, and I got this report from a user.

Can you help me understand the TCP connection entry to to this doubleclick Foreign Address? Is it a concern for the end user/organization? What could possibly open so many connections to doubleclick?

```
C:\Users\myPc>netstat

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5939         doubleclick:49713      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27017        doubleclick:51340      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27017        doubleclick:51341      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27017        doubleclick:51354      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27017        doubleclick:51626      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49677        doubleclick:49678      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49678        doubleclick:49677      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49680        doubleclick:49681      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49681        doubleclick:49680      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49705        doubleclick:49706      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49706        doubleclick:49705      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49713        doubleclick:5939       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49722        doubleclick:49723      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49723        doubleclick:49722      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50570        doubleclick:50572      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50572        doubleclick:50570      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50573        doubleclick:50574      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50574        doubleclick:50573      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50575        doubleclick:50576      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50576        doubleclick:50575      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50579        doubleclick:50580      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50580        doubleclick:50579      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50581        doubleclick:50582      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50582        doubleclick:50581      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50583        doubleclick:50584      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50584        doubleclick:50583      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50585        doubleclick:50586      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50586        doubleclick:50585      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50617        doubleclick:50618      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50618        doubleclick:50617      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50619        doubleclick:50620      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50620        doubleclick:50619      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51340        doubleclick:27017      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51341        doubleclick:27017      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51354        doubleclick:27017      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51626        doubleclick:27017      ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doubleclick is an ad service for websites. What you are seeing is someone who went to a web site that had doubleclick ads. Web browsers will open multiple connections when viewing a web site in order to download multiple parts of a web page simultaneously.